# 英語を喋りますか？ Can you chat online using the English language?

Tags: words

Is 英語を喋りますか the proper way to ask someone if they can chat online using English?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can".  Are you trying to ask if they have the ability?  Or are you asking permission, meaning "may you chat in English"?

Comment: @istrasci, I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are some of the ways I've seen being used(but from japanese people asking if the other person could speak japanese):

> 英語は大丈夫ですか。- Eigo wa daijoubu desu ka. - Is english ok?
>
> 英語で話してもいいですか - Eigo de hanashite mo ii desu ka. - Is it ok if we speak in english?
>
> 英語が話せますか。 - Eigo ga hanasemasu ka. - Can you speak english?

Answer (score 0):

As @Felipe_Oliveria has given the way to ask someone about his English speaking capabilities in Usual ways.
But you want your words in the proper way then you should use

> "英語でお喋りしますか。"

From "喋ります" to "お喋ります" will make it more polite.
Also, the "で" particle is usually used for any Language / Medium. 
like 英語で、日本語で.
Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: `お喋ります` -- Maybe you meant to type 「お喋り**し**ます」?

Comment: @Chocolate, I will use お喋りしますか

Comment: @Jack そですね～「英語でおしゃべりしましょうか。」「英語でおしゃべりしませんか。」とかがいいかもね。。